# Sum Two Columns in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aggregate-functions, sql-null

I'm trying to sum two columns data and put in a new column. However, I keep getting null values when I try the following.

```
select metric_name,metric_id,site,week,past,future,abs(sum(past+future)) as total 
from base_table 
group by metric_name,metric_id,site,week,past,future


metric_name         metric_id   site   week     past         future 
Forecast Est.Hrs     1001       HYD   W26-2020  84.435718       0
Forecast Est.Hrs     1001       HYD   W25-2020  78.606683       0
Forecast Est.Hrs     1001       HYD   W01-2021  0              78.606683
Forecast Est.Hrs     1001       HYD   W02-2021  0              78.606683
Forecast Est.Hrs     1001       HYD   W43-2020  10.9           78.606683
```

I need the output in the following way

```
metric_name         metric_id   site   week     past         future          Total
Forecast Est.Hrs     1001       HYD   W26-2020  84.435718       0             84
Forecast Est.Hrs     1001       HYD   W25-2020  78.606683       0             78
Forecast Est.Hrs     1001       HYD   W01-2021  0              78.606683      78
Forecast Est.Hrs     1001       HYD   W02-2021  0              78.606683      78
Forecast Est.Hrs     1001       HYD   W43-2020  10.9           78.606683      89
```

Please Help. This is used to work in mysql, but Redshift I'm getting null in the total column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why use aggregation in the first place? It seems like you just want an integer addition, so:

```
select metric_name, metric_id, site, week, past, future, 
    cast(past + future as int) as total 
from base_table
```